# A problem on Euclidean Geometry of of similarity of triangles, squares and angles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, quadratics, quadrilateral

(Solved)

I have this problem:

> In the figure we have a square $ABCD$ with diagonal $BD$ and the segment $AM$ such that $M$ belongs to the side $BC$ and such that $\overline{MC} = \overline{MP}$ where $P$ is the intersection of $AM$ with $BD$.
>   Find the measure of $\angle BMP = \alpha$.
>   [image]

So I tried a little bit. I drew on Geogebra and I´ve $\alpha = 60^{\circ}$. But I could not do this.
I know that $\Delta ADP$ is the similarity of $\Delta MBP$ because of $\angle DAM = \alpha$. 
I considered $d(A,D) = a$ and $d(M,C) = y$ and this implies $d(B,M) = a - y$. 
With this, I tried a lot of relations using law of Sinus and law of Cosines and some corresponded with this similarity. I don´t have success.
I tried to use Analytic Geometric too. I considered $A=(0,0)$, $D=(a,0)$, $C=(a,a)$, $B=(0,a)$ and $M=(a-y,a)$ I used the equation $y = -x +a$ that contains $BD$ and I know that I have a circumference of centre M and radius $MC$. But I can´t find the angle $\alpha$.

(Solved). Thanks too much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AB=a$ and $PM=MC=b$.

Thus, since $\Delta BMP\sim\Delta DAP,$ we obtain:
$$\frac{BM}{AD}=\frac{MP}{AP}$$ or
$$\frac{a-b}{a}=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+(a-b)^2}-b}$$ or
$$(a-b)\sqrt{2a^2-2ab+b^2}=2ab-b^2$$ or
$$(b^2-2ab+a^2)(b^2-2ab+2a^2)=(b^2-2ab)^2$$ or
$$(b^2-2ab)^2+3a^2(b^2-2ab)+2a^4=(b^2-2ab)^2$$ or
$$3b^2-6ab+2a^2=0$$ or
$$b=\frac{3a-\sqrt{3a^2}}{3}$$ or $$b=a-\frac{a}{\sqrt3}.$$
Thus, $$BM=\frac{a}{\sqrt3}$$ and $$\tan\alpha=\frac{a}{\frac{a}{\sqrt3}}=\sqrt3.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The triangles BPM and APD are similar. Then, $\frac{AD}{BM}=\frac{AP}{PM}$, or,

$$\frac ax = \frac zy\implies \frac {a+x}x = \frac {z+x}y=\frac{AM}{a-x}
\implies a^2-x^2=xAM$$

Substitute $a^2=AM^2-x^2$,

$$\frac{2x^2}{AM^2}+\frac x{AM} -1=0\implies \cos \alpha=\frac x{AM} = \frac12$$

Thus, $\alpha = 60^\circ$.

Comment: That's $\dfrac{z+\color{red}y}{y}$.